# Can Aurelia be loaded as a Webpack external?

Tags: webpack, aurelia

We would like to load Aurelia as a Webpack external to speed up build times of our code when debugging and help keep our Aurelia packages consistent across multiple projects. I attempted to require all the Aurelia packages and assign them to a global:

```
import * as framework from "aurelia-framework";
import * as history from "aurelia-history";
import * as historyBrowser from "aurelia-history-browser";
...

window["cdnAurelia"] = {
    framework: framework,
    history: history,
    historyBrowser: historyBrowser,
    ...
};
```

Then reference them as an external when building our Aurelia application:

```
var webpackConfig = {
    externals: {
        "aurelia-framework": "cdnAurelia.framework",
        "aurelia-history": "cdnAurelia.history",
        "aurelia-history-browser": "cdnAurelia.historyBrowser",
        ...
    },
    entry: {
        main: [
            "./src/main.ts"
        ]
    },
    ...
};
```

Which results in an error stating "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module "aurelia-loader-context"(…)" in aurelia-loader-webpack at:

```
var result = require('aurelia-loader-context/' + path);
```

Has anyone had success trying to load Aurelia as a Webpack external? Any suggestions on what to try next?

Answer (score 1):

I'm the maintainer of the Aurelia Webpack Plugin and we're working on some changes to make this possible, unfortunately at the moment there is no way to accomplish this.

Feel free to open an issue on GitHub to track this problem in the webpack-plugin repository.